# How to get correct day number in my country?

Tags: php, date

I'm using `date('j')` function in calendar. The problem is that it returns not correct day. For example in my country today is day 17 and this function return day 16. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `date` returns the date and time based on the server's time. Check out the output to the following:

```
<?php
echo date(DATE_RSS);
?>
```

This will tell you the current exact time and date that the sever is set to.

Remember, the server is a computer just like your own - only it is probably located somewhere half-way around the world. Just as your computer's clock is set to the local time where your are located, the server's clock is probably set to the local time where it is located.

However, you can use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in PHP to set the time and date you want to use in a script. This will change the default timezone used in that script.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your system which timezone you're in by [setting the timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: @Lina And read this: `Instead of using this function to set the default timezone in your script, you can also use the INI setting date.timezone to set the default timezone.` - it's more correct way.

Comment: Not all hosting companies will allow access to php.ini. It's not always an option.